Link problems in Rust undefined reference to `initscr'
I am working on a pseudo OS using Rust and c++, I am trying to detect the keys pressed using c++ with ncurses (I am aware that there is a similar crate for Rust) and in the build.rs I have the following code
cc::Build::new()
        .cpp(true)
        .file("src/button.cpp")
        .flag("-lncurses") // Link with ncurses library
        .compile("button.a");

But at the moment of making cargo run I get the following errors:
> undefined reference to `initscr'.
> undefined reference to `cbreak
> undefined reference to `noecho
> undefined reference to `stdscr' 
> undefined reference to `keypad 
> undefined reference to `stdscr' 
> undefined reference to `wgetch'
> undefined reference to `printw'

The code in which the error occurs is as follows:
// This code is provided by ChatGPT for testing purposes

#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {

void button() {
initscr();
cbreak();  
noecho(); 
keypad(stdscr, TRUE); 
int key;
while (true) {
key = wgetch(stdscr);
if (key == KEY_DOWN)
printw("Arrow down");
else if (key == KEY_UP)
printw("Arrow up");
else if (key == KEY_LEFT)
printw("Arrow left");
else if (key == KEY_RIGHT)
printw("Arrow right");
else if (key == '\n')
printw("Return");
else if (key == 3)
break;
else if (key < 256)
printw("%c", key);
else
printw("Special character");
printw("\n");
refresh(); 
        }
endwin();
    }
}

I am trying not to get these errors when charging run

Despite the name, very little linking actually happens when you create a static library. Your rust code (or the sample C++ code here) must also link with libncurses

@Botje Not familiar with Rust, but isn't .flag("-lncurses") supposed to do just that?

Me neither, but this is the moral equivalent of g++ -c src/button.cpp;  arc rcs button.a button.o.

Seeing @Botje comment that it was a equivalent of doing

g++ -c src/button.cpp;  arc rcs button.a button.o

I looked for information and managed to fix it by doing:
cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/button.cpp")
        .compile("button");

    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/button.cpp");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=ncurses");


Centos Stream 9
dnf install ncurses ncurses-devel
cargo new cxx-ncurses; cd cxx-ncurses; mkdir include
cxx-ncurses/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "cxx-ncurses"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
cxx = "1.0"

[build-dependencies]
cxx-build = "1.0"

cxx-ncurses/build.rs
// build.rs
//
fn main() {
  cxx_build::bridge("src/main.rs")
  .file("src/ncurses_test.cc")
  .std("c++11")
  .compile("cxx-ncurses");

println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/main.rs");
println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/ncurses_test.cc");
println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/ncurses_test.h");
println!("cargo::rustc-link-search=native={}", "/usr/lib64/");
println!("cargo::rustc-link-lib=dylib=ncurses");

cxx-ncurses/src/main.rs
// src/main.rs

#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {
  extern "Rust" {
    fn callback_rust(message: &str);
  }

  unsafe extern "C++" {
  include!("cxx-ncurses/include/ncurses_test.h");

  fn start_ncurses(message: &str);
  fn call_cplusplus(message: &str);
  }
}

// rust code
fn callback_rust(message: &str) {
  println!("rust: {}\r", message);
  let msg = message.to_uppercase();
  ffi::call_cplusplus(&msg);
}

fn main() {

  // You'll see this print when ncurses completes
  println!("rust main() starting....");

  ffi::start_ncurses("blocking on ncurses...");

  // You'll see this print
  println!("rust main() completed.");
}

cxx-ncurses/src/ncurses_test.cc
#include "cxx-ncurses/include/ncurses_test.h"
#include "cxx-ncurses/src/main.rs.h"
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses/curses.h>

void start_ncurses(rust::Str message) {

  // You will not see this until ncurses completes
  std::cout << "c++: " << message << std::endl;

  // Initialize ncurses
  initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();

  printw("\n\rType r to invoke the rust callback\n\rType q to quit\n\r");
  char c = ' ';
  while (c != 'q')
  {
    c = getch();

    if (c == 'r') {
      callback_rust("message from ncurses loop");
    }
    else {
      printw("c++: You typed %c try r or q\n\r",c);
    }
  }

  endwin(); // End ncurses mode

}

void call_cplusplus(rust::Str message) {
  std::cout << "c++: " << message << "\r" << std::endl;
}

cxx-ncurses/include/ncurses_test.h
// include/ncurses_test.h

#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "rust/cxx.h"

void start_ncurses(rust::Str message);
void call_cplusplus(rust::Str message);

cargo run
